# Does a for loop "delete" it's last looping from memory, or does it keep building in memory making run time slower?

Tags: c++

So I have a question.

This is a segment of my code from the main.

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAXVALUE; i++){
  for(int k = 0; k < vecMaxSize;k++){
  int randNum = rand()%MAXVALUE;
  vectorInts.push_back(randNum);
  }
...
  sortVector(vectorInts);
  //Print vector here...
}
```

Basically what I want to do is populate a vector, vectorInts, with random integers, then sort the Vector, then print it.

But i'm wondering. Every time I loop through the outer for loop and increment i, does the data get stored in memory, making the computer less efficient, as I keep looping? Or does this data get "deleted", every time I increment i?

Thanks!

Comment: Which "data" are you referring to? Obviously push_back makes the vector bigger every round.

Comment: The "data" I am referring to is what would be on memory, so the vector. So basically, everything inside the outer loop.

Comment: Since you "print vector here", wouldn't you trivially **see** how your code behaves? I don't understand which bit is unclear.

Comment: Yes, I see how my code is behaving, but i'm not exactly sure if it's correct. My times are increasing slowly, but I'm worried that each time loop through, I am increasing the memory impact on my computer making the code run slower. But it seems the other poster has answered my quesiton

Answer (score 2):

> But i'm wondering. Every time I loop through the outer for loop and increment i, does the data get stored in memory, making the computer less efficient, as I keep looping?

Looking at your posted code, `vectorInts` seems to have been defined outside the outer for loop. If that is indeed true, `vectorInts` will keep on getting bigger as you iterate over the loops.

Whether that makes the computer slow depends on how much memory is available on your computer and how big `vectorInts` gets.

Based on:

> Basically what I want to do is populate a vector, vectorInts, with random integers, then sort the Vector, then print it.

you probably want `vectorInts` to be defined inside the outer `for` loop and outside the inner `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAXVALUE; i++){
   std::vector<int> vectorInts;
   for(int k = 0; k < vecMaxSize;k++){
      int randNum = rand()%MAXVALUE;
      vectorInts.push_back(randNum);
   }
   ...
   sortVector(vectorInts);
   //Print vector here...
}
```

That will make sure that `vectorInts` will be created at the start and deleted at the end of every iteration of the outer `for` loop.

---

As @paddy pointed out in a comment, it will more efficient if you create the vector with the required size outside the `for` loop and just use its elements using the array indexing operator rather than using `push_back`.

```
// Create the vector with the known size.
std::vector<int> vectorInts(vecMaxSize);
for(int i = 0; i < MAXVALUE; i++){
   for(int k = 0; k < vecMaxSize;k++){
      int randNum = rand()%MAXVALUE;

      // Set the element of vectorInts.
      vectorInts[i] = randNum;
   }
   ...
   sortVector(vectorInts);
   //Print vector here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you R Sahu! Is it possible to use vectorInts.clear() or vectorInts.erase() instead of declaring it inside the for loop? Would there be a benefit to using one over the other if I could use it?

Comment: @MattI, you can do that but it is NOT idiomatic.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by idiomatic?

Comment: @MattI, When using C++, you should create objects in the smallest scope possible. If you don't need `vectroInts` outside the outer `for` loop, don't create it there.

Comment: That makes sense..  Thank you very much!

Comment: That said, there are times when you would definitely re-use the object at a higher scope rather than incurring the cost of redundant memory allocations.

Comment: @paddy, very true indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point your attention on the fact that

```
int randNum = rand()%MAXVALUE;
```

will not produce real random number, it is incorrect way, the numbers will not be generated uniformly

rand() returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX. RAND_MAX depends on library implementation. 
To understand the issue, imagine that on your system RAND_MAX is 15, and your MAXVALUE is 10. Then number 3 can come from 3 and 13, while number 6 can come only from 6. Thus numbers 0,1,2,3,4 has double chances to outcome from rand()%MAXVALUE, comparing to chances of numbers 6,7,8,9...

If MAXVALUE > RAND_MAX, then some numbers will never be achieved in rand() call.

There are other ways to generate uniformly generated random numbers.

Comment: Very good to know! Thanks for that!
So then is there a way to uniformly generate random numbers?